# Showing alert from other function

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I'm trying to show alert from other function in my ionic app. here is what i do

```
console.log(response); //return true
if (response) {
  this.successAlert;
} else {
  this.failedAlert;
}
```

and here is my alert that inside function

```
successAlert() {
this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: "Success"
  }).present();
}

failedAlert() {
this.alertCtrl.create({
    title: "Failed"  }).present();
}
```

but when i click it, there is no alert showing, what did i miss ?

UPDATE--
Here is full code of`home.ts`

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, App ,LoadingController,AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders,HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Events } from 'ionic-angular';


@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
    loginData = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
                public app: App,
                public ld: LoadingController,
                public http:HttpClient,
                public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public events: Events
                ) {


  }

  signIn(){
    let loader = this.ld.create({ content: "Please wait..." });
   //   loader.present();

        var headers = {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' : 'POST'

            };

        let bodyString = JSON.stringify(this.loginData); 
          this.http.post('http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login',this.loginData)
            .subscribe(
                    function(response) { 
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response)
                        {
                            this.successAlert();
                        }   
                        else {
                            this.failedAlert();
                        }
                    },
                    function(error) { 
                        this.failedAlert();
                    }
            );
    }

    successAlert() {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "Success",
         subTitle: '10% of battery remaining',
          buttons: ['Dismiss']
      }).present();
    }

    failedAlert() {
    this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: "Failed"  }).present();
    }

  }
```

I already try to change

`this.successAlert;` to  `this.successAlert();`

But i get this error

> TypeError: this.successAlert is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call function with paranthesis

```
if (response) {
  this.successAlert();
} else {
  this.failedAlert();
}
```

---

**EDIT**

> I already try to change `this.successAlert; to  this.successAlert();` But I get this error: *TypeError: this.successAlert is not a function*

Just like [@Suraj Rao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4826457/suraj-rao) mentioned in the comments, you need to use *Arrow functions*, like this:

```
// ...          
this.http.post('http://192.168.3.223:84/fppb/andro_login',this.loginData)
    .subscribe(
       (response) => { // <---- Here!
            console.log(response);
            if(response) {
                this.successAlert();
            }   
            else {
                this.failedAlert();
            }
        },
        (error) => { // <---- And here as well
             this.failedAlert();
        }
     );

// ...
```

Comment: i get this `TypeError: this.successAlert is not a function`

Comment: @YVS1102 `function(response)` use arrow function. Also here `function(error)`